# Python - Break a loop after an hour

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm looking for some help on how to break a loop after a certain amount of time. In the example below, it is after 2 minutes. However, having some trouble as it's ending.

1. Print Stuff
2. Wait 10 seconds
3. Do that 5 times
4. Wait 2 seconds
5. Do 1-3 again
6. Do all that for 2 minutes (or configurable time)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
t_end = time.time() + 60 * 2
while True:
    for b in range(2):
        for i in range(5):
            print("Stuff")
            time.sleep(10)
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Next")
    if time.time() > t_end:
        break
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code now? What "trouble" is it having?

Comment: It’s not breaking after 2 minutes.

Comment: Hm, it's breaking for me. I wasn't timing it, but I set it to run in the background and it did end eventually

Comment: Thanks for checking. I’ll try again and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah looks good actually. The inner `sleep`s are pretty long though, so the checks on the timeout only occur at most every 104 seconds only from those... Assuming "stuff" takes no time, your test should abort after approx. 208 seconds (3min:28sec).